# C++11 : narrowing

Tags: c++, c++11, narrowing, list-initialization

I read the below paragraph in the PDF: http://www.stroustrup.com/what-is-2009.pdf

> > Narrowing
> >
> > Maybe you noticed that I used {} initialization consistently. Maybe, you also thought that I was uglifying code and was overenamored by a novel feature? That happens, of course, but I don’t think that is the case here. Consider:
> >
> > ```
> > int x1 = 64000;
> >
> > int x2 { 64000 };
> > ```
> >
> > We can have a nice friendly discussion about the aesthetics of those two definitions and you might even point out that the {} version requires one more keystroke than the = one. However, there is one significant difference between those two forms that makes me chose {}. The {} version doesn’t allow narrowing and I failed to tell you that the two definitions were written for a machine with 16-bit ints. That means that the value of x1 could be very surprising, whereas the definition of x2 causes a compile-time error.

But when I tried compiling the following using 'Ideone.com' c++11 online compiler it showed success

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  // your code goes here
  short i {999999};
  std::cout<<"value of i = " << i;
  return 0;
}
```

I was expecting compilation error. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: using compiler on same site?

Comment: check this http://ideone.com/v6TBec

Comment: warning with g++ 4.7.2. needs to put warnings into errors. Likely something like that happens in ideone too.?

Comment: @herohuyongtao which compiler are you using?

Comment: @herohuyongtao: check the error statement, it may not be in context to this.

Comment: @ShinTakezou: can you share the warning statement?

Comment: two warnings: `warning: narrowing conversion of ‘999999’ from ‘int’ to ‘short int’ inside { } [-Wnarrowing]` and then `warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]` too.

Comment: @ShinTakezou: can you refer me a good online compiler for c++11?

Comment: If you want to be in control of how you compile and using which compiler, I think the better way is to install a compiler on your machine. If you can't, I've find [this](http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp11_online.php) just now; at least, it shows you the compiler  options and its output.

Comment: @vikramjitSingh use http://rextester.com with clang compiler

Comment: @herohuyongtao VisualStudio 2010 does not suppport list-initialization.

Comment: @vikramjitSingh A fairly recent clang++3.5 is available in coliru: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/497ae2d58275a0ce

Comment: I'm testing that code on GCC4.8.2 and I can't reproduce the Stropustrup's behavior too. BTW g++ says: *"Narrowing conversion from long int to short inside { }"* (Note that I have added more zeros, thats why its a `long int` instead of an `int`)